# PGFPlots cycle list skips first definition after every cycle

Tags: pgfplots, color, plot

I got some problems with self-created cycle lists in PGFPlots.
As you can see, the plots skip the first definition of my cycle list after every run through the cycle list. Are there any coding mistakes, i didn't recognize?

The same error occurs when using `mycyclelist` with `cycle multi list`

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz, pgfplots}

\definecolor{UniBlau}{cmyk}{1,0.7,0,0}
\definecolor{UniGruen}{cmyk}{0.6,0,1,0}
\definecolor{UniOrange}{cmyk}{0,0.3,1,0}
\definecolor{UniRot}{cmyk}{0.4,1,0,0}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycyclelist}{
{UniBlau, line width = 2pt},
{UniGruen, line width = 2pt},
{UniOrange, line width = 2pt},
{UniRot, line width = 2pt},
{UniBlau!50!UniGruen, line width = 2pt},
{UniGruen!50!UniOrange, line width = 2pt},
{UniOrange!50!UniRot, line width = 2pt},
{UniRot!50!UniBlau, line width = 2pt},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
stack plots=y,stack dir=minus,
cycle list name = mycyclelist]
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Hopefully you can help me.

Many Thanks!

Comment: I think you just have a comma too much after `{UniRot!50!UniBlau, line width = 2pt},`, i.e. after your last definition. It cycles your 8 colors and does than an empty one (thin black line) which is the 9th, empty one after that comma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing your definition of the cycle a little bit by removing the final `,`, which introduced an empty style for the 9th line and adding `%` for stability (didn't compile on my system without them) you get

```
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycyclelist}{%
  {UniBlau, line width = 2pt},%
  {UniGruen, line width = 2pt},%
  {UniOrange, line width = 2pt},%
  {UniRot, line width = 2pt},%
  {UniBlau!50!UniGruen, line width = 2pt},%
  {UniGruen!50!UniOrange, line width = 2pt},%
  {UniOrange!50!UniRot, line width = 2pt},%
  {UniRot!50!UniBlau, line width = 2pt}%
}
```

[image]

Comment: Many Thanks! That works very well as suggested!